# Cannot execute AsyncTask after onPostExecute fired

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a class that extends `AsyncTask`. I use Interface to get result from `onPostExecute()` of my class and it works fine. The problem is when I get result from executed task (witch means **current task is finished** ) I need to execute  another task by **same instance of that class** but I get this error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running
```

Where is the problem and how should I fix it? Why Previous task still is alive?

Comment: Create new AsyncTask object and execute it.

Comment: better post your code here

Comment: @quicklearner solved , thanks ;)

Comment: what did u do for it?

Comment: @quicklearner  created new instance of class just as answer says :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reuse the same `AsyncTask` object. Create a new one:

```
CustomAsyncTask task = new CustomAsyncTask();
task.execute("");
...
// This will result in crash
// task.execute("");

task = new CustomAsyncTask();
// This is ok
task.execute("");
```

[Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#608) the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: what if I do this : 
newtask = oldTask ;
newtask.execute();

Comment: won't work , then `oldTask` will just have another name i.e  `newtask`

Comment: Nope, that won't work out. What's the problem with creating a new `AsyncTask`?

Comment: cause I need that object's properties

Answer (score 2):

From [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to `being executed on a single
>   thread` to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution.

So once a thread has been started , you cannot start it again , simply create a new object of your task and apply exexute

`execute` internally calls `executeOnExecutor`

```
 public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
        return executeOnExecutor(sDefaultExecutor, params);
    }
```

and from `executeOnExecutor` [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...))

> Throws:
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException If getStatus() returns either
>   AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING or AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED.

Comment: created new instance of that object , but same result again

Comment: what you mean by `new instance of that object` , you need to create an instance of your `AsyncTask`  class , provide precise details about what you want to do and what you are doing

Comment: one important thing, seems like you need data from your first call , so you probably should start next task from `onPostExecute` when your first task is finished and you have the data to use

Comment: with new instance , its ok . but I need same instance ! I have made lots of changes to its properties and need those variables

Comment: why can you just start another asynhtask from `onPostExecute` and pass those value to `execute` function or pass those values to some function and start new task from their or if your asych task is a separate class then create interface callbacks